# Uncaught ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined - Switch to universal analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I recently updated to universal analytics and now push event data to the datalayer, rather than using the old _gaq. I've gone through my code and removed all traces of _gaq, however, when events are firing i'm getting the following error message:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined**

It appears that there are still some references inside the following file:

**http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js**

Is it possible to refresh this script so that it removes any references to _gaq?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Gtm.js will contain references to _gaq only if you have put them there, either by setting up a "classic" Google Analytics tag or by using the _gaq variable in a custom HTML tag or custom Javascript variable (gtm.js is simply a bundle of the boilerplate GTM code plus any tags you have configured via the interface).  It is rather more likely that you overlooked some inline tracking call. In any case, clicking on the error message in the browser console should give you the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, Thank you, Eike. You were absolutely correct about a rogue _gaq reference existing in GTM.